# How to send UDP client message in smart way to the UDP server parse the message

Tags: python, qt, sockets, udp, protocols

I have an application in PyQT (UDP client) that send some parameters over UDP/IP to an application on raspberry (UDP server).

This Qt application has several fields like PID parameters, speed of the motor, sensors presets and so on.

Actually, the UDP client sends a string by getting the values from each field in the QT application and appending the data into the string with separator character (','), always in the same sequence. For instance, "142.0, 10.0, 2.0, negative, positive".
The UDP server receives this message, splits the message and moves each item of the list to the respective variable.

It works, but it is not smart, all parameters are sent even when one the parameter is not changed.

Whats should be the smart way to send only specific parameters, not depending of the right sequence? or only the changed ones?

Maybe some encapsulate protocol over the UDP message?

Comment: This question feels not quite appropriate for this forum. You are likely to receive replies supported only by opinion, each equally valid. Having said that, I'd use JSON so my message would look like `{'x':142,'y':10,'attitude':negative','outlook':'positive'}`

Comment: @Robᵩ Single-quoted strings are *not* standard JSON. Some decoders permissively allow them, but that doesn't mean that you should knowingly advocate producing such JSON output. Your message example should be `{"x":142,"y":10,"attitude":"negative","outlook":"positive"}`.

Comment: @KubaOber - You are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep things simple and change the existing code the least, you can include empty values for parameters with values that didn't change. E.g. if you have four parameters, then assuming they all changed you'd send `142,10,2,negative,positive`, but if only the first two changed you'd send `142,10,,`. But, such ad-hoc schemes should be IMHO discouraged.

You could use [json](http://www.json.org) with very short member strings. E.g.`{"a":142,"b":10}`. You'd have to keep a human-readable mapping between the short string keys and their meaning separate from the data. Since the strings can be any Unicode character, you have quite a way to go before you ran out of single characters to use. Also, Python [natively supports json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

If you don't care much about the length of the packet, then you don't even need short member strings: make your packets-self documenting by using meaningful strings, such as `{"velocity":142,"acceleration":10}`.